# What to put in the tag wiki of TV shows when there are several seasons?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Currently, the [true-detective](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/true-detective) tag wiki excerpt says:

> An American television crime drama series following the lives of two detectives, Rust Cohle and Martin Hart, who become entangled during a 17-year hunt for a serial killer in Louisiana.

Which is specific to the first season only.

Wouldn't it be better if it will be something more generic, e.g. this?

> Anthology series in which police investigations unearth the personal and professional secrets of those involved, both within and outside the law.

(from [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2356777/).)

I considered just suggesting such edit, but not sure about this site policy, wanted to ask first.

Answer (score 6):

There is no site policy that forbids you suggesting a tag wiki edit.

We would welcome you improving this or other tag wikis.

However as you point out the summary you propose is word for word from IMDb (and Rotten Tomatoes for that matter) so unless it comes with a clear license that it can be re-used, would potentially be copyright infringement and not allowed.  Some original text would be required.

Comment: Sure, but question is would it be considered helpful? e.g. today I learned that saying which season the question is about is not helpful and is being edited out, so wonder about other such things.

Comment: The wiki as it stands today is inaccurate or incomplete - I see no reason why it should not be updated.

Comment: I have no context around (and cannot find) where you were told that saying which season would be unhelpful, so I can't address specifics - but if this related to a tags, we don't typically put seasons in tags because there are generally so few questions per tag that this seems unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, I found what you are referring to - which was the removal of the series name and season from the title of the question.  This is common, we typically remove the name from the title because that is what the tags are intended for.  The season number was essentially part of that edit.

Comment: It makes the titles smaller and cleaner and puts an emphasis on having accurate tags.

Comment: Nonetheless an edit of the tag wiki would be welcome.  With an anthology series like True Detective I might argue that this could include a sentence or two about each season/